# runuser in rc.local

Tags: users, init, linux

I have to setup port forwarding on system start and have this configured in my rc.local

```
runuser -l phpAdmin -c 'ssh -f -N -L 9904:localhost:3306 phpAdmin@<server>'
```

When rc.local is executed, is it executed as root?

Comment: You really have an user `phpAdmin` in /etc/passwd, with a valid shell entry?

Comment: If this a rhetorical/sarcastic question, I am missing it. Could you please elaborate? Is this a bad security practice?

Comment: I'm searching for an explanation why it's not running as user phpAdmin.

Comment: It is working fine, I just want to make sure that this is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rc.local is executed as root user, but this is not probably the place to start such tunnel because if you get any problem (even a temporary network problem), your tunnel will be stopped forever. A better solution is to put it in /etc/inittab file, so that your init process may run it in your correct runlevel, and respawn it if it crashes.
If you run it from inittab remove the "-f" flag from ssh invokation, otherwise init will not be able to detect ssh failing.

Comment: Do you mean add an entry in inittab itself or create an entry like /etc/init.d/foo with foo having the port forwarding script?

Comment: in inittab, like "TT:23:respawn:/bin/su phpAdmin -c 'ssh ...'"

Comment: Now that we are on it, a question, what is the difference between doing it in init tab versus adding another entry under init.d? If you can point me to a link also, I would be very happy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in inittab you just put a command line and it will be executed when init switch run level. In init.d you store scripts and you may invoke them with an argument (usually start/stop/restart/status) and you may have many scripts in the same runlevel (just link them from /etc/rcN.d where N is the runlevel) and you may sort them. More info to /etc/init.d startup sequence depends on what startup procedure you are using: check all "upstart" "systemd" "sysv-rc"